# Why degree equals to the intersection number with general linear space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}_{K}^{N}$ be an irreducible projective variety where $K$ is an algebraically closed field. Let $\text{dim}(X)=d$. As in Chapter I of Hartshorne's book, we may define $\text{deg}(X)$ as $d!$ times the first term of the Hilbert polynomial of $X$. But there is another definition in for example [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_an_algebraic_variety), saying that degree equals to the intersection number with a general linear space of codimension $d$. I try to formulate this statement as follows:

For hyperplanes $(H_1,\dots,H_d)$ in an open dense subset of $((\mathbb{P}_{K}^{N})^{\vee})^d$, $X\cap H_1\cap\dots\cap H_d$ is reduced and contains exactly $\text{deg}(X)$ closed points.

Could you please help me figure this out? I guess this might be a Bertini type result. Indeed, using appropriate Bertini theorems, I'm convinced that the result is true if we choose the general hyperplanes *sequentially*, i.e. the general hyperplane $H_i$ depends on $H_1,\dots,H_{i-1}$. But it seems that this is weaker than the statement above. Thank you!

Comment: The origin of the degree of a variety is that by Bezout for a hypersurface it’s the degree of the defining polynomial. You could get a maybe very singular hypersurface from any variety by projecting, intersect with a hyperplane there and unproject the situation?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Maybe the intersection with general hyperplane will always have good properties?

Comment: Take the twisted cubic, project to a singular cubic in the  plane intersect with a line, unproject to the twisted cubic intersected by a plane, maybe you can follow the hilbert polynomial definition thruogh these steps?

Comment: Maybe you could test your intuition on [the Horrocks-Mumford surface in P4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75968/horrocks-mumford-surface-and-other-surfaces-in-mathbb-p4)?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: I'm just a beginner at algebraic geometry and I find it hard to deal with that surface of degree 10... Does that example very helpful to the general question? Or do you think that is a counterexample (since I'm not sure why you mention that specific example)?

Comment: It’s just an example that’s not a curve and not codim one. A fellow student back when used a computer to find the equations. The twisted cubic curve is codim two, and should be instructive, though.

Comment: There’s always the linear algebra case of linear spaces themselves. A plane in P4, say. Cut with a hyperplane, it will give a line, cutting again gives a point, et voila, degree one. Maybe the [complete intersection case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3194786) is what you’re looking for. The search for smooth codim two varieties that are not complete intersections is mentioned in the original paper of Horrocks and Mumford in Topology from 1973. The proof of theorem 5.1 there uses some intersection theory; there’s enough to get by in Hartshorne.

Comment: Do you happen to know of the moving lemma, or the deformation to the normal cone construction of Fulton-MacPherson in intersection theory?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Thank you for your comments! I have heard the moving lemma, but I don't know the latter construction.

Comment: I suggest reading a bit in [3264 & All That
*Intersection* *Theory* *in* *Algebraic* *Geometry*](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf).

Comment: Also, the Hilbert polynomial is constant in flat families

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: OK, thank you! I will read it.